# Filter language in solr

Tags: solr

I indexed  German and English docs with solr and i want to some ability to search just inside German docs or English docs,How to configure this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the options as mentioned @ http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/LWEUG/Multilingual+Indexing+and+Search

You may end up with having to implement multiple language fields and language detection.

Answer (score 1):

Have a field indicating the language, and search on that.